# web app for use as a toolbar to open other programs

Tags: javascript, html, css, uitoolbar

I need a toolbar program, that opens other programs by clicking on the respective link. Is it possible to realize this as a Web App with HTML, CSS and JS?

I'm a beginner, i didn't try it

Comment: so you're asking for something that opens apps via browser right? Like first open ur browser -> click button -> open excel

Comment: Exactly this. The browser isn't necessary, in the end it can also be a desktop application. But since i'm a beginner, I started recently by learning html/css/js and it should involve this stack to prevent confusion about other languages :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean with programs it is possible to create a toolbar program as a web application. You can create buttons with links to other programs and use JavaScript to open the programs (eg websites) when the buttons are clicked. for example like so:

```
  <div class="toolbar">
  <button onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com')">Google</button>
  <button onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com')">Facebook</button>
  <button onclick="window.open('https://www.youtube.com')">YouTube</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but i like to open programs that are installed on the computer like SAP, Excel, etc. as well as different drives or documents.

Comment: This is not easily achievable